# ls command is too slow for some directories

Tags: linux, lvm, ls, hard-disk, io

When I run `ls` command for some directories, it may take about 1.5 seconds to complete even if directory has just a few files, but for most of directories it's very fast. It seems that it's slow for directories which I didn't access for a long time, but maybe it's not related. When I repeat this command for same directory it always run fast.
This command is slow **only** for directories on `/home` mount point, for all other partition on same volume it's fast.

E.g. my `~/backups` dir contains just 3 files, here is output for 2 runs:

```bsh
$ time ls ~/backups
# file list
real    0m1.635s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.000s

$ time ls ~/backups
# file list
real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.000s
```

My `/home` is formatted in `ext4` fs, it's a `lvm2` partition encrypted with `LUKS`, the volume is a HDD "WDC WD10SPZX-75Z".

`fstab` line for `/home` is:

```
/dev/mapper/home /home ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
```

Is it possible to improve IO performance in my case?

**UPDATE**: it's not only `ls` command, but all io operations, e.g. `touch` command is also slow when I try to modify directories which I didn't access for a long time.

**UPDATE2:** the output of `lsblk` for `sda` drive:

```
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda              8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─HDD-root     254:3    0    32G  0 lvm
├─HDD-var      254:4    0   256G  0 lvm
│ └─var        254:8    0   256G  0 crypt /var
└─HDD-home     254:5    0   512G  0 lvm
  └─home       254:7    0   512G  0 crypt /home
```

output of `findmnt`:

```
TARGET                          SOURCE               FSTYPE      OPTIONS
/                               /dev/mapper/root     ext4        rw,relatime,commit=600
├─/proc                         proc                 proc        rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ └─/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc    binfmt_misc          binfmt_misc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
├─/dev                          udev                 devtmpfs    rw,nosuid,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=2013980,mode=755
│ ... (some /dev related mount points)
├─/sys                          sysfs                sysfs       rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ... (a lot of /sys and cgroups mount points)
├─/run                          tmpfs                tmpfs       rw,nodev,relatime,size=1612028k,mode=755
│ └─/run/user/1000              none                 tmpfs       rw,relatime,mode=700,uid=1000
├─/home                         /dev/mapper/home     ext4        rw,noatime,commit=600
│ └─/home/projects              /dev/mapper/projects ext4        rw,relatime,discard,commit=600
├─/var                          /dev/mapper/var      ext4        rw,relatime,commit=600
└─/tmp                          tmpfs                tmpfs       rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,size=4194304k
```

Comment: How is the health of your HDD? Have you ran any SMART tests?

Comment: @JakubLucký yes, I used `smartmontools`, it completes without error. Also, another volume-group on same HDD is working fine.

Comment: Could it be due to LUKS? please add the output of lsblk and findmnt

Comment: Does the hard drive spin down too soon maybe, and then requiring some time to spin up again?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa done, please see "UPDATE2" section in question

Comment: @Kusalananda I don't think so, it happens on actively working environment, and `/var` partition on same HDD doesn't have this issue

Comment: Try these two commands to get a simple MB/s read metric. This will by-pass the filesystem and read directly from the LUKS container: `dd if=/dev/mapper/home of=/dev/null count=65535` and `dd if=/dev/mapper/var of=/dev/null count=65535` If both metrics are about the same then the bottleneck is in the filesystem and not in LUKS nor LVM. Otherwise, drop down a layer to by-pass LUKS: `dd if=/dev/HDD/home of=/dev/null count=65535` and `dd if=/dev/HDD/var of=/dev/null count=65535`.